# How to display HTML page in flash using only action script 3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I have been trying to display html content inside flash SWF for few hours now, my approaches were:

- using htmlText on dynamic TextField - works fine, I have added regexp to check if ' / " signs are present around attributes because lack of those break the display of the text at first occurence:

  ```
  var attrPattern:RegExp = /=([^('|")][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/g;
  var fixedHtml:String = unfixedHtml.replace(attrPattern, "='$1'");
  ```

  unfortunately colors like 'red' doesn't work, but '#FF0000' does. I could add some table lookup to fix the colors but I found another solutions I wanted to try before that,
- MiniHtml worked well, but it needs well-build html file with all of the tags matched, for example it requires matching /br to br - I made some regexp replaces but unfortunately code like:

  ```
  <p> this is <b>bold</b> text</p>
  ```

  is not accepted by the XML parser,
- HTMLLoader - seems to be for AIR only,
- htmlWrapper - I have tried really hard to find an example that would show the code inside of flash AS 3.0. The project seems to be discontinued, I have tried to use it but without documentation I was not able to get very far - if anyone have any examples of how to use it please share
- ASTRID - whole MVC in AS, have some html renderes as htmlWrapper, there is no example of how to use the renderer in flash

Thanks in advance for any examples or propositions of different approaches to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use TLF. [Text Layout Framework](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-1b8898a412218ad3df9-8000.html) has great factories to parse and display HTML content, but It's all about, how complex html do you like to display. It you want display full html page, TLF will not help you in this task. But if you work with html formatted content, TLF is a good choice. Check capabilities of TLF for [HTML rendering](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use StageWebView ?

Comment: i would have to publish as AIR

Comment: StageWebView works with AIR in all 'profiles' except AIR for TV. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html

Comment: Should be no problem. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc16ddeea2126bb46b82f-8000.html

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running in browser there is one more option but it's a bit dirty.
You can use browser to render html. Use ExternalInterface to create and place <*iframe*> over your swf. Then put necessary html code inside this *iframe*.

Yes, it's strange solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTextBox:TextField= new TextField();
myTextBox.width = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.ScreenWidth;
myTextBox.top = 0;
myTextBox.bottom = 0;
myTextBox.multiline = true; 
myTextBox.wordWrap = true; 
myTextBox.htmlText = "<html><body>bla bla</html>"; 


var wrapper:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
yourGroup.addElement(wrapper);

wrapper.addChild(myTextBox);
```